# Swift 3 - SceneKit Get 3d model scale value

Tags: swift3, 3d, scale, scenekit

I am trying to get the value of a 3d object loaded into`sceneView` while it is being scaled using two fingers. I can correctly get the `rotation`, `position` and `orientation` however, the `scale` stays always on `1`.

How can I get this value?

```
var update = Timer()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        sceneView.scene = SCNScene(named: "PKB2");
        sceneView.debugOptions.insert(SCNDebugOptions.showWireframe)
        sceneView.autoenablesDefaultLighting = true
        sceneView.allowsCameraControl = true

        update = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.01, target: self, selector: #selector(self.updateFunc), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

    } 

func updateFunc() {

        var eulerAngles_x = Double((sceneView.pointOfView?.eulerAngles.x)!) * (180.0 / Double.pi)
        if( eulerAngles_x < 0 ) {eulerAngles_x += 360.0}

        var eulerAngles_y = Double((sceneView.pointOfView?.eulerAngles.y)!) * (180.0 / Double.pi)
        if( eulerAngles_y < 0 ) {eulerAngles_y += 360.0}

        var eulerAngles_z = Double((sceneView.pointOfView?.eulerAngles.z)!) * (180.0 / Double.pi)
        if( eulerAngles_z < 0 ) {eulerAngles_z += 360.0}

        x_lbl.text = String(format:"%.2f", eulerAngles_x)
        y_lbl.text = String(format:"%.2f", eulerAngles_y)
        z_lbl.text = String(format:"%.2f", eulerAngles_z)
        w_lbl.text = String(format:"%.2f", (sceneView.pointOfView?.scale.z)!)

        print(sceneView.pointOfView?.scale) // not changing while scaling the object

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using `sceneView.allowsCameraControl = true` you are manipulating the camera, not the object. Your 3D object is not moving, the camera is moving around it.

Therefore it's wrong the check the scale of the camera, as the scale isn't changing, it's just zooming in.

Try checking `sceneView.pointOfView?.camera.xFov` and `sceneView.pointOfView?.camera.yFov` instead.

---

Also it's worth noting that the docs for `allowsCameraControl` state:

> Note that the primary purpose of this property is to aid in debugging
>   your application. You may want to implement you own camera controller
>   suitable for your application.

Comment: Thank you. I understand you point what is moving is actually the camera view. Using xFov I can see the camera zoom. So How should I control the rotation and scale of object and not the camera? Any stack or tutorial you can point me out?

Comment: Add your own gesture recognisers to the scene for panning and pinching, and use the translation and scale values. You may still want to move the camera rather than the object, but using your own gestures will give you much more control.